# Show attachments as icon by default in Mail OS X El Capitan

Tags: mail.app, macos

I would like not to show attachments previews in the app "Mail" in OS X El Capitan, but just show icons.
Following the guides, I have tried this command in the Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

but is seems that, for El Capitan, this doesn't work properly, since in the Inbox folder, attachments aren't shown as icons.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted the following into terminal and it works correctly for me. All attachments appear immediately as icons in El Capitan Mail:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
```

It appears to be exactly the same as you entered it above. Before entering the command, I closed Mail and relaunched it after the command had been accepted in terminal. Don't know what to say other than it worked for me. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Steve, I did as you instructed and sent an email to myself with the attachment.  When it gets sent, the attachment is visible as like a normal attachment, but when I receive it back, its back to being an open document.  Attachment Tamer is the only one that has worked for me so far, but Adam has not updated for El Capitan unfortunately.